# Get a specific instance from an API object with one of the [key, value]

Tags: javascript, object

I have an API which send to me an object of 5 instances with each 5 properties. I would like to get an object from one of this property.

Here's one of the instance from the API object :

```
 {lenses: ["35mm 1.4","50mm 1.6"],_id: "5be1ed3f1c9d44000030b061",name: "Zurss 50S",price: 49900,description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temporincididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",imageUrl: "http://localhost:3000/images/vcam_1.jpg"},
```

I have the value of the _id, I would like to get the entire instance which have this _id.

Tank you for your help !

Comment: If the API returns an array of objects, use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method to find the object with the given id within the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this you can

```js
var p=arr.find(x=>x['_id']==<id>)// Here you have to pass id which you have
```

```js
var arr=[
   {
      "lenses":[
         "35mm 1.4",
         "50mm 1.6"
      ],
      "_id":"5be1ed3f1c9d44000030b061",
      "name":"Zurss 50S",
      "price":49900,
      "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temporincididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "imageUrl":"http://localhost:3000/images/vcam_1.jpg"
   }
]

var p=arr.find(x=>x['_id']=='5be1ed3f1c9d44000030b061')

console.log(p)
```

Comment: I am just assuming that you are getting array of object

Answer (score 0):

From what you say, the API is returning something like this

```js
 [
    { ... },
    {
     lenses: ["35mm 1.4","50mm 1.6"],
     _id: "5be1ed3f1c9d44000030b061",
    name: "Zurss 50S",price: 49900,
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do    eiusmod temporincididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    imageUrl: "http://localhost:3000/images/vcam_1.jpg"
  },
  { ... }
]
```

That means you have an array of Objects. There are many methods to traverse the array and operate with elements.
To accomplish what you are asking, you can use the [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const apiResult = [{
     lenses: ["35mm 1.4","50mm 1.6"],
     _id: "5be1ed3f1c9d44000030b061",
    name: "Zurss 50S",price: 49900,
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do    eiusmod temporincididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    imageUrl: "http://localhost:3000/images/vcam_1.jpg"
  }
]

const obj = apiResult.find((apiObj) => apiObj._id === "5be1ed3f1c9d44000030b061")

console.log(obj)
```

You can even create your own function to pass any id you want:

```js
const apiResult = [{
     lenses: ["35mm 1.4","50mm 1.6"],
     _id: "5be1ed3f1c9d44000030b061",
    name: "Zurss 50S",price: 49900,
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do    eiusmod temporincididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    imageUrl: "http://localhost:3000/images/vcam_1.jpg"
  }
]

function getObjWithId(id) {
  return apiResult.find((apiObj) => apiObj._id === id)
}

const obj = 

console.log(getObjWithId("5be1ed3f1c9d44000030b061"))
```